# How does one hire "The A-Team"

Tags: the-a-team

[image: A-Team]

<sup>[[Archived source](https://web.archive.org/web/20130313195834/https://www.nerdsraging.com/2012/08/06/retro-tv-shows-the-a-team/#main-content)]</sup>

[**The A-Team**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_A-Team) intro [says](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N1HMCArgqWM):

> ***... If you have a problem, if no one else can help, and if you can find them, maybe you can hire... the A-Team.***

*The A-Team* is on the run from the *military police*, so they can never stay in the same place for long and therefore travel all over the country.

Nonetheless, people in need of their help are somehow able to *find them*? But it's not like the A-Team puts out ads for their services with their current contact information attached.

How did people initiate the first contact with the A-Team?

Comment: Why, do you have a job for us?

Comment: Nowadays it could have been through the dark web...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

These are a few episode starters I remember:

- People contact Amy/Tawnia because they heard that she is connected to the A-Team and want her to pass the message (after which Murdock sets up a meeting...)
- People put out an advertisement in the newspaper seeking for help and the A-Team responds
- People go to someone (which turns out to be Hannibal) who said they could contact the A-Team

More unrelated episode starters:

- The A-Team learns that Amy/Tawnia is working on a story and wants to fight that injustice
- Some old friends of the A-Team are in trouble and they decide to go help
- They find themselves in a sudden rough spot (e.g.one of Face's deals goes wrong) and the episode deals with it

Comment: I remember that for (3) Hannibal would ususally disguise himself, but I don't remember how people found that _someone_ in the first place.

Comment: @Oliver_C it could be through the people the A-Team previously helped. As they helped a lot of people, most of those people would be grateful. When they hear someone is in trouble they could contact Hannibal and inform them/act as intermediary ("I know a guy that knows a guy..."). As the A-Team helped them in the past, it's not likely they would betray them by contacting Decker or someone else

Comment: Well, thanks to [Six Degrees of Separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_degrees_of_separation) the _"friend of a friend"_ explanation can actually cover a lot of different people.

Answer (score 3):

They must first meet with Mr. Lee, who is in fact Hannibal in disguise. This allows them to sort those who need help from those who may want to capture the team or just use them.