# What was the name of the mysterious organization they sometimes referred to?

Tags: the-a-team

In the TV show the [The A-Team](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_A-Team), there was a mysterious organization they sometimes referred to. I can't remember if they worked for that organization but it was called something a bit like "The Organization" or "The Authority." Does anybody know what it was?

[image]

Picture stolen from [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/5699/how-does-one-hire-the-a-team) because it is great.

Comment: Not sure if it was A-Team sounds more like Airwolf where the goverment agency was called "the Firm" and in the fourth season "the Company".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the plot section of the of the [A-Team](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_A-Team)'s wiki:

They were on the run from *Military Police* for about four seasons until their ratings began to decline.  Once captured, they were blackmailed into working for a mysterious CIA operative by the name of General Hunt Stockwell to perform missions for him, and he participated as well.

Depends on the episode, you may have to pull up a script to see if this is before they are working for the CIA.  They could refer to "The Agency" at that point but before then, they were on the run from "The Authorities" (which is more general and doesn't refer to one specific group).

Comment: Oh maybe it was the Agency!